# If $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e. and $\{f_n\}$ are bounded in $L^r$ for $r>1$, then $\int f_n \rightarrow \int f$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be a general bounded smooth domain. Suppose that $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e. in $\Omega$, $f_n\geq 0$, and there exists some constant $C>0$, which is independent of $n$, such that
$$
\int_{\Omega}f_n^r\,dx\leq C.
$$
My question is that is the following convergence relationship valid
$$
\int_\Omega f_n\,dx\rightarrow\int_\Omega f\,dx?
$$
If this convergence relationship is valid, how to prove it? It seems that the DCT and Fatou's lemma do not work here, and I haven't found any similar theorem in my reference book.

Thanks for any hints and help!

Comment: This is a standard application of the notion of úniform integrability and it has been answered earlier on this site.

Comment: See also here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem